# When typing, mouse stops moving

Tags: 12.04, keyboard, mouse

i did a clean installation of Ubuntu 12.04 recently and all is well, except
for one small thing. When i type anything and anywhere with the keyboard, i cant move the mouse.

So for example when i am playing a game which requires two hands like Nexuiz, i can only move the character but i cannot turn around simultaneously.
Ubuntu runs on a desktop PC.

I have a standard cheap Logitech keyboard and the
most common Microsoft mouse. 
I tried connecting the keyboard or the mouse, or both together on the PS/2 hub but it's still the same.

Any suggestions considering the solution of this problem are welcome.

Also note that i have already tried the 'Disable touch while typing' from dconf-tools with no result.
Thanks in advance to anyone who replies.

Comment: I have the exact same problem. Have you found out why this is happening? And what to do? I have normal USB keyboard and mouse.

Comment: Sounds like some kind of hardware conflict with USB. You could try different USB ports.

Answer (score 0):

Is it possible that your mouse has been recognized as a touchpad? By default, touchpad is disabled when typing. Go to the settings / mouse and touchpad, and inspect the options there.